# Apache Arrow adapter Integration with Apache Calcite

Tags: apache-calcite, apache-arrow

Is there any option readily available to integrate apache arrow and apache calcite?

I observed that CSV, JSON has this integration feature. but Apache Arrow doesn't have this.

we have to write all these classes like [calcite-arrow-sample](https://github.com/masayuki038/calcite-arrow-sample) since its not readily available from api it self.

Comment: Could you explain what kind of "integration" you are talking about?

Comment: @wes-mckinney : we have to write all these classes [calcite-arrow-sample](https://github.com/masayuki038/calcite-arrow-sample) since its not readily available from api it self.

Comment: can see [here all the classes related to api integration](https://github.com/masayuki038/calcite-arrow-sample/tree/master/src/main/scala/net/wrap_trap/calcite_arrow_sample) but not built in some one has hand written all the code for integration of arrow and calcite.

Comment: all the above code was written in scala not in java. if its provided by calcite api in java many users even scala users can import and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive research, found that This feature is not readily available as of today and have to write the code following [calcite-arrow-sample](https://github.com/masayuki038/calcite-arrow-sample)

. I wrote this feature in java emulating the code features in above link.